# POST request to Django DRF call working in cURL but not with Postman

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework, postman

I'm following the instructions to support TokenAuthentication in my rest-api site, shown [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication). Using cURL, I have been able to obtain my user's token (username - example, password - example), through the following command:

```
curl -X POST -d "username=example&password=example" localhost:8000/api/login/
```

This returns a successful  response, with example's authentication token.

Yet when I do (what I think is) the same thing through Postman, it simply does not work. See image below.

[image: Postman response]

From the error code (400 - Bad request), it seems like it's not even receiving the POST parameters at all. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your URL in postman. There is attached query String with the URL.So remove that query String from the URL and send parameters as a post request like this.

```
http://localhost:8000/api/login/
```

Comment: This did it. I had to put the post parameters in the body of the request, not in the query. Thank you very much. I'll accept the answer, as soon as it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

Even this is very old question, but if this answer would be helpful...
I had exactly same issue

solution:
don't put username and password in address bar,but only

[image]

and in body put json data of your username and password as below

[image]

be careful, don't use single quotation marks'', but use double quotation marks "" instead, otherwise will fail, no clue why

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your API is set up, you probably need to specify the content type in your request headers, `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: I actually copied all the headers that cURL used and tried it on Postman, to no avail. I then tried only the Content-Type, also no go. Plus, I am already getting a JSON response, just not the correct one.

Comment: Right, the content type header tells the server what you are SENDING. Can you show the working curl headers?